# ArcGIS Server: Limit Access to Port 6080 Based on IP?

Tags: arcgis-server, security, services

We have an ESRI ArcGIS Server 10x in our intranet which listens on both port 80 (through the Web Adaptor) and port 6080. So the web "Services" are accessible from both ports. I want to limit access to who can access the Services based on IPs. In case of port 80, it was fairly easy: Using IIS Manager, select the virtual directory and then using the "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" feature assign the allowed IPs.

But how to restrict based on IPs for port 6080? I think I could simply disable port 6080 and use 80 but that would require some applications to be adjusted.

Comment: You didn't specify it, but you're using a Windows operating system -- How about using the firewall?

Comment: Yes, Windows. I did look into Windows Firewall but the sys admins control that.

Comment: Yet that is your sole solution (and the reason this will be closed as off-topic).

Comment: So you are saying that there is no configuration for 6080? Isn't it some Tomcat engine?

Comment: I guess I will have to check with the Windows sys admins for port 6080. Thanks